# Cannot access Swagger UI from public IP/Server (works on localhost)

Tags: node.js, swagger

I can access my swagger UI from local host perfectly. I am trying to do the same on my computer. I have sorted out port forwarding and I receive response from my application, but it seems to be not pulling all the required information.

This is my app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cors = require("cors");
const compression = require('compression');
const swaggerJsdoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
require("dotenv").config();
require("./auth/passport");
require("./mySqlDB/relationships")


const middlewares = require("./middlewares");
const api = require("./api");

const app = express();

app.use(compression()); //Compress all routes
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "I am runnig",
  });
});

app.use("/api/v1", api);

const swaggerDefinition = {
  openapi: '3.0.0',
  info: {
    title: 'API',
    version: '1.0.0',
  },
  //basePath: "/api/v1"
};

const options = {
  swaggerDefinition,
  explorer: true,
  // Paths to files containing OpenAPI definitions
  apis: ["./src/api/*"],
};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJsdoc(options);
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));

app.use(middlewares.notFound);
app.use(middlewares.errorHandler);

module.exports = app;

//DB connection
require("./mySqlDB/connection");
```

In my index.js I just start the app:

```
const app = require("./app");

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening: http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

This is what I get when trying to access it using my IP:
[image]

Also this what I can see in VS Code, it only pulls the api/docs, not the rest:
[image]

I assume this is probabaly just a setup issue

Comment: you screenshot suggesting ssl error , are you sure that your app is configured correctly to handle https requests ?

Comment: When I run an API request in the browser it works with normal http, should not that mean that Swagger should work too? So as an example myIP:myPort/api/getData returns stuff.